Movie with monsters, a giant ship and a bomb!
Scenes I remember

Towards the end of the film a bad guy drinks something (I think drinks) and becomes bigger than the good guy's monster and then fights him 
Good guys have an Indian guy (I think Indian) who owns a massive submarine or a ship with a massive army
Towards the end, a bomb goes of in the city and the good guys are in a car and trying to drive away 
I think from what i remember the city was in the snow


Please provie more info like which year , when you saw , any other plot elements . More you tell , more chance we will be able to identify

I think the movie you are looking for is The League of Extraordinary Gentlemen?
The guy who drinks something to become big is Dr.Jekyll. 
The Indian is Captain Nemo. 




@andrew, was this the one you were looking for?

haha, he just missed it looks like.
